# What is a "payload adapter"?

Tags: payload, integration

What is a "payload adapter"? For example, from the following page:

> The IXV Intermediate eXperimental Vehicle installed on its **payload adapter**, on 26 January 2015 at Europe's Spaceport in Kourou, French Guiana.

— [IXV Installed on its Payload Adapter](http://www.esa.int/spaceinimages/Images/2015/01/IXV_installed_on_its_payload_adapter2), ESA Space in Images

Comment: Similar: [Can all satellites/spacecraft be used interchangeably with all launch vehicles?](http://space.stackexchange.com/q/5958/49)

Comment: Also see [Secondary Payload definition](http://space.stackexchange.com/q/3534/49)

Comment: It is a structure that works as an interface between the spacecraft and the launcher. During launch the s/c is attached to the adapter which in turn is attached to the launcher

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Payloads come in different shapes and sizes. To put them on a specific launch vehicle, you need to either design the payload to fit perfectly onto the rocket or you need some sort of **adapter** to mount it in place. It's also common to launch multiple payloads with a single launch, so you need some mechanism to separate the different payloads and release them into their respective orbits.

For more information, see [the Wikipedia article on the ESPA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EELV_Secondary_Payload_Adapter)